# Associate file extension to UWP Windows 10 app not in "Open With" list

Tags: windows-10

I want to open a certain file extension with a Windows 10 UWP (Microsoft Store) app.

I right-click on the file in File Explorer, select `Open With`, then `Chose another app` and I get the menu below, which does *not* include the app I want.

At this point, I can click `Look for another app on this PC`, but the app I need is an UWP one, which is not in the `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` folders, so I cannot just navigate to the path of the executable file.

How can I associate my extension to the UWP app?

(Nota that this is *not* a duplicate of the same question for non-UWP programs)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UWP applications are different from desktop applications.
If the UWP was programmed to open files of a certain type, it will automatically
be added to the "Open with" list. Otherwise it cannot be manually added
to this list.

A UWP app needs to be programmed to do the following in order to register for
a file type:

1. Specify the extension point in the package manifest
2. Add the proper icons
3. Handle the activated event

For more information see:

- [Handle file activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation)
- The official [Association launching sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AssociationLaunching) on GitHub
- [UWP: Open App by using File Type Extensions](https://codedocu.com/Details?d=1611&a=9&f=181&l=0&v=d)
  (using Visual Studio)

Comment: That's so... obnoxious. Why would they limit that...

Comment: @JasonC: UWP was badly designed, which is why it never took off.

Comment: We once had a conference at the MS offices with the director of Hololens dev and some Win 10 API devs; all I'll say is it was *so hard* to hold back 20 years of not-nice things I fantasized about saying to MS management. I mean... they were *right there*! Within slapping distance, and we outnumbered them 3:1!!  ... 